# Reset all my markerLayer in Mapbox

Tags: javascript, jquery, mapbox

i use Mapbox as a map to show company geoLoc on, my code is

```
var markerLayer = L.mapbox.markerLayer({
    type: 'Feature',
    geometry: {
    type: 'Point',
        coordinates: [value.GeoLng, value.GeoLat]
    },
    properties: {
        title: 'A Single Marker',
        description: 'Just one of me',
    }
}).addTo( $.mapbox.mapObj );
```

My problem is when i get a new json call and its return new locations did i don't know how i can reset/remove all my old markerLayer and its just add all the new to the map.

i have create a map obj. width jQuery as `$.mapbox.mapObj` so i hobe its posible to reset/remove all my markerLayers from my object and i soe can add all my new markerLayers on it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can reset marker layers with

```
markerLayer.clearLayers()
```

Comment: Yes found the problem, its becures i don't create a object for it... :/ now its working :) $.mapbox.layerGroupObj
      .addLayer( new L.marker(
       new L.LatLng(
        value.GeoLat, 
        value.GeoLng
        )
       )
       .bindPopup('This is Littleton, CO.')
       );
      
       $.mapbox.layerGroupObj.addTo( $.mapbox.mapObj ); thanks for you answare :)